# Документация по doc/sql.extensions/*.txt

Tags: документация, firebird

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли перевод документации doc/sql.extensions на русский у firebird 2.5?
Если да, то поделитесь ссылкой.
Спасибо.

Comment: [Хороший справочник по FireBird](http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=glossarij)